# Using getElementsByTag to change values in table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I've been trying to do this for the past couple of days, but my Javascript is HORRID. Extremely.

Basically, what Im trying to accomplish is taking the value in a td, and checking for a string of 10 digits. (Actually, any American formatted phone number. I've already come up with the regex.) I need to replace that string with something else (something that isn't a phone number).

The table structure looks like this:

```
    <tr id="76">
        <td class="stxt">
            <div class="dtxt" id="t1344992123" title="14 Aug 12, 08:55 PM">17 mins ago</div>
            <span>
                <a title="Delete">[×]</a>&nbsp;
                <a title="Ban User">[o]</a>&nbsp;
            </span>
            <b class="nme pn_std">Person</b>
            : This is a line a user has said previously
        </td>
    </tr>
```

There will be several rows that all have the same formatting. Where it says ": This is a line a user has said previously" is what needs to be checked for numbers.

The table format I have posted, is all I have to work with. Cannot add, and I cannot remove any tags/attributes.

If someone is just able to come up with the code for checking and replacing each instance of what Im searching for, I can insert the regex and replacement string myself.

And, if any one is curious, this is for a word filter for cbox chat. It is just something that will be run as someone loads the chat.

Anyone who can help me out would be amazing. Like I said, I'm weak at Javascript. PHP is the language I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't uniquely identify the element whose text you wish to replace, you need to iterate over all the text nodes and replace the ones with text that matches the regular expression (which you haven't shown us).

```
function processTable(id) {
  var table = document.getElementById(id);
  var cells;
  var re = /\d{10}/; // just an example
  var text = 'foo';  // just an example

  if (table) {

    // Could iterate over table.rows then row.cells,
    // but gEBTN seems suitable
    cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

    for (var i=0, iLen=cells.length; i < iLen; i++) {
      replaceText(cells[i], re, text);
    }
  }
}

// Recursively replace text in text nodes of elements
function replaceText(el, re, text) {

  var node, nodes = el.childNodes;

  for (var i=0, iLen=nodes.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    node = nodes[i];

    // Replace content of text nodes
    // Ignore script elements
    if (node.nodeType == 3 && node.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'script') {
      node.data = node.data.replace(re, text);

    // Recurse over elements to get child text nodes
    } else if (node.childNodes) {
      replaceText(node, re, text);
    }
  }
}
```

Some HTML to test it on:

```
<table id="t0">
  <tr>
    <td>1234567890
    <td><span>1234567890</span>
  <tr>
    <td>foo 1234567890 bar
    <td><span><b>1234567890</b></span>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.google.com">1234567890</a>
    <td><span>1234567890</span>
<table>

<button onclick="processTable('t0')">Do replacements</button>
```

The above should work in any browser supporting javascript, say since IE 5 (which I think was when IE started supporting getElementById, certainly IE 6 did).

Comment: This actually worked great for the examples, until I realized the script ends up being inside the table. So, realing on my non-existant javascript skills, I tried removing the function and table references, and changing "table.getElements..." to "this.getElements...".

It didnt like that. Haha. So what other change should be made for it?

And to answer your question on the regex Im using,
/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})/
which works great my other scripts, and was working on this script until I made the changes above.

Comment: I just noticed my typo... relying. (I hate typos... >_< )

Answer (score 2):

If you're not supporting anything below IE8 you can use the newer querySelectorAll. But following a comment I think I'll comment that out in favor of the older approach.

```
//var tableCells = document.querySelectorAll('#tableId td'),
var tableCells = document.getElementsById('tableId').getElementsByTagName('td'),
i = tableCells.length;

while(i--){
    var thisCell = tableCells[i];
    thisCell.innerHTML = thisCell.innerHTML.replace(yourRegEx,yourReplacementStuff);
}
```

Before somebody pipes up about regEx and HTML, keep in mind that he's just looking for phone numbers here, not to parse HTML with regEx. You could use regEx on the innerHTML property for the entire table, but I suspect looping and biting off smaller pieces might actually be quicker.

Comment: I'd use `var tableCells = document.getElementById('tableId').getElementsByTagName('td')`, as it's only slightly more complex and will work fine with older browsers.

Comment: Good point. Probably faster too since querySelector uses the CSS engine which is more focused on more general tags. People were goofing around with querySelectorAll in JS chat yesterday and performance results were somewhat surprising.

Comment: You may notice that the ID of the div inside the TD may well match the OP's regular expression (10 digits) so an innerHTML solution is not a good idea.